# How to get all content with an <h2> tag in WordPress?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Sample Content:

```
<h2 id="h2-1">H2 Heading (1)</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur ...</p>
<h3 id="h3-1">H3 Heading</h3>
<h2 id="h2-2">H2  Heading (2)</h2>
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href='#h2-1'>H2 Heading (1)</a></
  <li><a href='#h2-2'>H2 Heading (2)</a></li>
</ul>
```

I knew it can be done with a regex function but I don't know how to finish the function. Here's what I have done so far:

```
function table_of_contents() {
    $content = get_post_field( 'post_content', $post->ID );
    $tags = preg_match_all( '#<h2>(.*?)</h2>#', $content, $matches );

    return $tags;
}
```

Comment: And what's the result?

Comment: You should probably [use DOM parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Regex like this:

```
<?php
$content = '<h2 id="h2-1">H2 Heading (1)</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur ...</p>
<h3 id="h3-1">H3 Heading</h3>
<h2 id="h2-2">H2  Heading (2)</h2>';

preg_match_all( '@<h2.*?>(.*?)<\/h2>@', $content, $matches );
$tag = $matches[1];
var_dump($tag);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "H2 Heading (1)"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "H2  Heading (2)"
}
```

Details at regex101: https://regex101.com/r/RNeVI2/1